# How to implement a context menu for each item in a listView

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am coding a universal windows 8.1 application and I have very limited experience with context menus I have a `ListView` with items that are added to it as the user adds entries. I want each item in the `ListView` to have the same context menu so I made a flyoutMenu resource

```
<Page.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Name="flymenDelete">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"    Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then I add the menu to my listView

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvwHours" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource flymenDelete}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="264" Margin="427,77,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="357" RightTapped="lstvwHours_RightTapped">
</ListView>
```

and I have my event to handle the right click

```
private void Button_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);
}
```

The problem with this is it shows the a context menu but only for the actual `ListView` control and not the items inside the `ListView`. How do I have it so this context menu only appears when the `ListViewItems` are rightclicked keeping in mind that these items are not hardcoded and are added with the below code.

```
private void DisplayHours()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HList.Count(); i++)
    {
        lstvwHours.Items.Add(this.HList[i].display());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a flyout to list item by the utilizing ItemTemplate property of ListView.

Just define DataTemplate for an item and it will be applied to the each list item:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvwHours">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource flymenDelete}" RightTapped="lstvwHours_RightTapped" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```